# Prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^n \text{ mod }k > 2n$ where $n > 1000$

Tags: number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

This problem is taken from a Russian textbook of past Olympiads.

Its statement looks like this :

> Given a natural number $n > 1000$ prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^n  \text{ mod }k > 2n$.

Apart from a few basic considerations:

---

$2^n$ is not divisible by any odd number except $1$ so the remainder of $2^n$ divided by any such number will always be greater or equal to $1$,
 I haven't been able to make any notable progress from here.

---

The solution provided in the textbook is also very unintuitive, or at least I perceive it as such. The author sets out right off the bat to prove that

> $$S_n > \frac{n}{2}(\log_2n - 4), \text{ where $S_n$ denotes  $\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^n  \text{ mod }k$}.$$

Comment: Extending your observation: if $k=2^j m$ where $m$ is odd and greater than $1$, then $2^n\mod k$ is a nonzero multiple of $2^j$ and therefore is at least $2^j$. (Your observation is the $j=0$ case.) What lower bound on $S_n$ does this produce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me do the calculations. The method is the one pointed out by Greg Martin in the comments.

Suppose $k = 2^m \ell$, where $\ell$ is odd and $\neq1$. Then $$2^n \bmod k \geq 2^m$$
($2^n \bmod k$ is divisible by $2^m$, but non-zero).

Hence, counting the number of $k$'s of the form  above (for each value of $m$):
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} 2^n \bmod k \geq \sum_{m=0}^{\log_2 n -1}2^m \times \left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^m}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2^{m+1}}\right\rfloor - 1\right)
\geq \sum_{m=0}^{\log_2n-1}2^m \times \left(\frac{n}{2^{m+1}} - 2\right)$$

which is happily 
$> \frac{n}{2}\lfloor\log_2 n\rfloor- 2n$.